# How do I send an error packet to a single client in socket io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I want to be able to emit an error packet to a client, similarly to how it's used when [registering middleware](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace#use(fn:function):namespace).
This works:

```
var io = require('socket.io')();
io.use(function(socket, next){
  if (socket.request.headers.cookie) return next();
  next(new Error('Authentication error'));
});
```

This doesn't:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.emit('error', {errorMessage: 'errorMessage'});
    //or
    socket.emit('error', new Error('error'));
});
```

`Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.`

How do I emit an error event using the socket object?

Comment: Kindly, can you specify socket.io version?

Comment: @KirillSlatin version 1.2.1

Answer (score 9):

Event name 'error' is reserved for transport level errors.
When you will try

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.emit('exception', {errorMessage: 'errorMessage'});
});
```

it should work just fine.

Comment: This is just a regular emission, it is not an error packet. Either way, I want to handle severe errors using `socket.on('error', function(error){//errorHandler});`

Comment: At the same time `error` is reserved for transport level errors. Your business logic errors shouldn't occupy this name. It has different meaning from app errors

Comment: @KirillSlatin My BL isn't occupying this error handler, it is reserved for transport errors. And the fact that the docs say it can be invoked using the middleware, means I should be able to invoke it using the socket object, even for debugging purposes. The docs give a good example for usage - `Authentication errors`. Now I want to use the same error handler for various Authentication errors within my connection scope (socket object), and this is just one example for this usage.